# ObjectMapper ignoring configuration when annotations are present

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

My project is using `application.properties` file to set the property as following: `spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true`, which works in all cases but one:

```
class Model {
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public SubModel subModel;
}
```

simply commenting out the annotation causes ObjectMapper to fail as intended, but as soon as the annotation is added, the option set seems to be ignored.

How can I configure jackson to use annotations along with the config?

Comment: Is the option ignored only for that exact property or for all in that class / all classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to logic needed to pass down unwrapped properties from parent context, there is no way to efficiently verify which properties might be legitimately mapped to child POJOs (ones being unwrapped), and which not.

As of now it is not possible to make jackson to fail on unknown property with unwrapping.

Issue is still open ,

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/650

> How can I configure jackson to use annotations along with the config?

It is nothing to do with config or annotations, they are working fine.

Comment: thanks, I guess I'll go with inheritance for this one instead